# Create a undo/redo textboxes algorithm in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I would love to create a type algorithm Undo/Redo in VB.Net, first at least i want to make the undo.

if we have the example Textbox1.Text = `a,b,c`

then change to = `a,b,c,e`

then change to = `a,b,c,f`

when I click on `undo` I want to display (that is, the value before it. before after `a,b, c, f`, was `a, b, c,e`

```
a,b,c,e
```

and when I click once again I want to display

```
a,b,c
```

that is, an `undo / redo algorithm` of added values

I first created a global list.

```
Public Module Globals
    Public Undo As New List(Of String)
End Module
```

if Textboxes value is not exists in the list, then I will add it.

```
Private Sub Button1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Undo IsNot TextBox1.Text Then
        Undo.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

hey well here's the tricky part

```
Private Sub Undo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Undo.Click
    Dim i as integer = Undo.Count
    While TextBox1.Text IsNot Undo(i)
        TextBox1.Text = Undo(i)
    End While
 End Sub

   For i As Integer = Undo.Count To 0 Step -1
     TextBox1.Text = Undo(i)
   Next
```

unfortunately no such loop works in this case.

Comment: Even if we assume that by `Undo IsNot TextBox1.Text` you meant "not found in the list" (which it of course isn't), your code makes no sense and can be replaced with `TextBox1.Text = Undo(0)`. Undoing means restoring *the* previous state, not a previous unique state. Having changed the text `a` -> `b` -> `c` -> `b` -> `c` -> `a` -> `b`, you expect to undo it as `b` -> `a` -> `c` -> `b` -> `c` -> `b` -> `a`, not as `c` -> `b` -> `a`. There is nothing tricky about it either, you add each next state to the end of the list without thinking, and you restore the last added state without thinking too.

Comment: Just search "undo redo vb.net" and you will find numerous examples showing how to do this.  For examle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/general/how-to-undo-and-redo-an-action-in-a-text-box-or-a-combo-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Undos As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Private AddUndo As Boolean = True

Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If AddUndo = True Then
        Undos.Add(textBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Undos.Count <> 0 Then
        AddUndo = False

        If Undos.Count > 1 Then
            textBox1.Text = Undos(Undos.Count - 2)
            Undos.RemoveAt(Undos.Count - 1)
        Else
            textBox1.Text = ""
            Undos.RemoveAt(0)
        End If

        AddUndo = True
    End If
End Sub
```